# How to create composite primary key whether I already have a primary key definied. MySQL

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I have a table with primary key auto_increment and I am having a duplicate data problem. To solve this I tried to create a composite primary key but it's not possible: `#1068 - Multiple primary key defined.`

I can't drop the primary key because there are relationship with other tables and I can't just put Unique constraint in only one column because the rule is to be composite.

What can I do? I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying the primary key on a table is a tricky exercise. This is doubly true when the existing key is defined `auto-increment`.

You can create a composite unique key, though.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE KEY (`column1`, `column2`);
```

Comment: you have a single quote instead of a back-tick at the end of your code

Comment: ALTER TABLE tableName ADD UNIQUE KEY(myCol1, myCol2);

Comment: Edited for typos.